# How to upload adventureworks data into sas

Tags: sas, adventureworks

I wonder if one of you can help me on how to upload all adventureworks database (every table) into SAS Studio?

I would like to work on adventureworks using sas base

Comment: Have you extracted all the tables outside of whatever DB it's in? Or can you connect Base SAS to your server using a libname reference?

Comment: Hello! thanks for your reply! Actually i have my adventuresworks database (tables) on SQL. I need to put these tables into sas studio in order for me to use them via a libname ref, what do you thing? have a good evening :)

Comment: Connect to the SQL database using a libname connection - but note that if you're using SAS UE I don't think it allows DB connections. So if thats your situation you'll need to export the data and then import it into SAS.

Comment: I have SAS Studio so I guess its ok. Now, how can i connect to the sql database using a libname connection?

Comment: You  need to set up a DSN first on your computer and then you can connect to it: https://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts714.pdf

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is create a libname reference to your database - I don't recommend creating SAS tables from the raw SQL Server data.

Example libref (using OLE DB):

```
libname &libref OLEDB  
  PROPERTIES=&sql_properties 
  DATASOURCE=&sql_dsn  
  PROVIDER=&sql_provider 
  SCHEMA=&sql_schema  
  authdomain="&sql_domain" 
  connection=shared;
```

You will need to set the relevant variables as per your environment.

Answer (score 0):

It took a few years..  And the development of [sasjs](https://cli.sasjs.io)..  But finally, AdventureWorks for SAS is here!

Just run these two lines of code and the 5 AdventureWorks schemas will be created as different libraries under WORK:

```
filename mc url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sasjs/AdventureWorks/main/runme.sas";
%inc mc;
```

Just modify that file to make permanent libs / datasets.  More info in the readme:  https://github.com/sasjs/adventureworks